# SelectMany/Select - Flatten a many-to-many relationship

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

I have a main table called Task and each Task can be connected to zero or more Customers so I also have a Customer_Task many-to-many table. Basically what I want is to flatten the many-to-many relation to get the following result:

```
Task.Field1, ... ,Task.FieldN, Customer.Name, Customer.Number
```

So basically I just want the Task entity plus two more fields that should come from the many-to-many relation with the Customer entity.

I have only succesfully used Select/SelectMany once before, and that was a very simple case, so I figured I just ask the experts. Can anyone help me with this?

My guess would be something like this, but that does not work:

```
var tasks = _database.Task.SelectMany(t=>t.Customer_Task.SelectMany(c=>c.Customer.Name)).ToList();
```

Requested class structure (I have removed a lot of irrelevant information):

```
public partial class Customer
{
    public Customer()
    {
        this.Customer_Task = new HashSet<Customer_Task>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Number { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public partial class Customer_Task
{
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
    public int TaskId { get; set; }

    public virtual Customer Customer { get; set; }
    public virtual Task Task { get; set; }
}

public partial class Task
{
    public Task()
    {
        this.Customer_Task = new HashSet<Customer_Task>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Number { get; set; }
    public string Header { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Customer_Task> Customer_Task { get; set; }
}
```

The exception I get is ArgumentException:

```
System.ArgumentException was unhandled
Message=DbExpressionBinding requires an input expression with a collection ResultType.
```

Comment: Why it does not work? What is the error? Provide your class structure.

Comment: I have added the relevant parts of the class structure...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your requirements, then something like this should do:

```
var _database = new List<Task>
            {
                new Task
                {
                    Customer_Task = new List<Customer_Task>
                    {
                        new Customer_Task
                        {
                            Customer = new Customer {Id = 1, Name = "a"},
                            Task = new Task {Id = 1, Number = 1}
                        },
                        new Customer_Task
                        {
                            Customer = new Customer {Id = 1, Name = "b"},
                            Task = new Task {Id = 1, Number = 1}
                        },
                        new Customer_Task
                        {
                            Customer = new Customer {Id = 2, Name = "a"},
                            Task = new Task {Id = 2, Number = 2}
                        },
                        new Customer_Task
                        {
                            Customer = new Customer {Id = 2, Name = "b"},
                            Task = new Task {Id = 2, Number = 2}
                        }
                    },
                }
            };
            var tasks = _database.SelectMany(t => t.Customer_Task.Select(c => new { Task = c.Task.Id, Name =c.Customer.Name})).ToList();
            foreach (var t in tasks)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(t.Task + " "+t.Name);
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
```

Where the result is:

1 a
1 b
2 a
2 b

So you can change your query from

```
var tasks = _database.Task.SelectMany(t=>t.Customer_Task.SelectMany(c=>c.Customer.Name)).ToList();
```

to

```
var tasks = _database.Task.SelectMany(t=>t.Customer_Task.Select(c=>c.Customer.Name)).ToList();
```

Comment: That worked somewhat, but wouldn't that require me to list all the Task properties in the Select statement?

Comment: Like : var tasks = _database.SelectMany(t => t.Customer_Task.Select(c => new { Id = c.Task.Id, Header = c.Task.Header, Name =c.Customer.Name})).ToList(); Since this entity has 30 or more properties I would like to not have to do that...

Comment: Yes, in the Select statement you should list all needed properties. Or you can just select Task itself, if you need task. Like  var tasks = _database.SelectMany(t => t.Customer_Task.Select(c => new { Task = c.Task, Name =c.Customer.Name})).ToList();

Comment: The problem with the last one is that I will later use this in a databound report and it would be a lot easier if I could bind it to the Task entity. And the problem with the first solution was the number of properties on the Task entity, but if listing all properties is what I have to do, then I'll guess that is what I have to do. Thanx!

Comment: But you can easily get the task entity! Just select the task itself, like I've shown in the previous comment. As result you will have anonymous object containing Task entity and Customer name string. Let me know if there are any issues with that.

Comment: I think I understand what you mean, I'll experiment with it and we'll see if I get it to work.